# Matrix property more specific than being triangular -- each next row starts with more zeros.

Tags: matrices, definition

I am looking for a name of a following matrix property: each next row has more starting zeros than the last one. The last few rows can all be full of zeros.

I was trying to search for that but found nothing...

Regarding upper triangular/trapezoidal matrices - that is **not** what I want.
For example $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ is upper triangular but doesn't satisfy my property.

Regarding the reasons for why I'm looking for this: I think that LUP-decomposition can be generalized onto rectangular matrices with both factors not only being triangular, but also U having this property I described and L having a similar one for columns. Haven't found much on that side either...

Comment: Are you looking for the term "echelon form"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form

Comment: @Ernie060 exactly! Thanks a lot. You wonna make your comment into an answer?

Comment: Ok, it's not necessary for me, but if you want, I'll make it into one. Just glad I could help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the term [row echelon form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form). By Gauss elimination every matrix can be transformed into this form.